# Can a Necromancy wizard raise a Spawn of Kyuss?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, undead, necromancy

Are there any spells out there that would allow a necromancy school Wizard to specifically raise a [Spawn of Kyuss](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/spawn-of-kyuss)?

Or would controlling one only be achievable through turning it?

Answer (score 8):

There is no spell, ability, or magic item in the RAW that allows a PC to summon/create any undead other than zombies or skeletons (Animate Dead spell), ghouls, ghasts, wights, or mummies (Create Undead spell), or specters (Hexblade warlock's Accursed Specter feature).

The only exceptions are Wish, which of course lets you attempt anything if you are willing to take the risks of a non-standard spell effect, and the cleric's Divine Intervention feature, whose description allows the DM to have your deity create up to the equivalent effect of a Wish on your behalf, if granted and with whatever cost it exacts of you.

NPC necromancers, on the other hand, can do whatever the DM wants them to be able to do - and this does not mean, or imply, any kind of symmetry meaning a player character should also also be able to do it. Monsters and NPCs are not bound by the same class, racial, or other features that a PC has access to; they can have non-standard spells, or even just have abilities from nowhere.

Clearly the DM can rule that a PC can gain access to such an ability/spell, etc., but that is not RAW and becomes a house rule for that table.

Comment: Hexblade warlocks raise [specters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/specter), not [shadows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shadow).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not an official spell that would allow you to raise a Spawn of Kyuss under your control, but you can ask your DM to allow you to create a homebrew spell that would let you do that. The DMG's DM's workshop section contains good information that could help you with this, though it should be kept in mind that the highest level necromancy summoning spell creates cr 3s, and that is a lv 6 spell, so keep that in mind when choosing a spell level

Comment: Might be worth noting the Spawn is CR5, and the highest CR that can currently be raised in CR3 with a 6th level spell if they're planning on homebrewing a solution.